# problem getting value from jsp to servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get value of count (which is 1) from the parent jsp page into servlet.
  But it gives an error: "opener.document.getElementById(...)is null or not an object".
  Is this because i'm trying to get value without submitting the form??
  Will be glad if someone could help.

jsp:

```
 <td> <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="1"></td>
```

servlet:

```
 out.print("var oWindow = window.external.menuArguments;");
        out.println("var ctr=oWindow.opener.document.getElementById(\"count\").getAttribute(\"value\");");
```

Comment: "count" is this available in the page, or this will be coming back after the submission of the page??

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on which page window, oWindow, or oWindow.opener is pointing to, do you really have 3 client-side window objects involved in this operation?  Perhaps it should just be:

```
var ctr=oWindow.document.getElementById('count').getAttribute('value');
```

...or you should give a little more information as to the structure of your application.  For example, window.external is for when you have extended MSIE and added your own context menu item, this has very little to do with servlets.

Comment: There is a button Open File, when clicked on it, it gets url of the file from parent window<tr><td><b>Destination File  : </b></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="dest1" id="dest1" value="" size="60"></td>
                         <td> <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="1"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" id ="1" name="but1" value="Open File" onclick="OpenDestFile()" ></td>
                    </tr>

Comment: M sorry, when clicked on open File it opens a file in new window.

Comment: Then  when I select a phrase in that file and right click and say "Choose as Destination" control goes to servlet page where i need the count value.

Comment: In which case I have no idea why you're using window.external.menuArguments.  Just use window.opener directly: `var ctr=window.opener.document.getElementById('count').value;`

Comment: tried var ctr=window.opener.document.getElementById('count').value: gives error : 'window.opener.document'is null or not an object.. But this function RetURL returns url of the parent page with oWindow.opener in the same servlet. out.println("function RetURL(){");
            out.println("var oWindow = window.external.menuArguments;");
            out.println("var oDocument = oWindow.document;var oUrl=oDocument.URL;");
            out.println("return oUrl;}");

Comment: If there's no such thing as `window.opener.document`, that means that there is no parent window of the window that the code is currently running in. Servlets have nothing to do with JavaScript errors, your servlet is just generating more JavaScript.  It sounds like you are asking for help with something that you don't fully understand because you didn't create it. In which case you need to give a more complete description of what your application does for somebody who knows nothing about your application to help you. What version of IE is it? You might be better off opening the debugger.

Comment: Error fixed. Thanks for your responses. Well.. error was not with respect to count value, but was with respect to the field where value had to be filled.